# Unable to 'select' new POCO from two source table using ServiceStack Orm Lite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am attempting to select a POCO using data from multiple different source tables using [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite).  I'm following the general syntax shown under [C# 7 Tuples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#c-7-value-tuples), but returning a concrete POCO instead of a Tuple.  I'm getting an parsing the `SqlExpression`.

```
 var exp = Db.From<TransactionProduct>()
                        .Join<Transaction>()
                        .Join<Product>()
                        .Join<Transaction, Device>()
                        .Select<Transaction, Device>((t, d) =>
                        new BottleBox
                        {
                            Location = d.Name,
                            Notes = t.Note,
                            Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
                        });
```

The error is:

```
Error CodeInvalidOperationException
Messagevariable 't' of type 'BMS.ServiceModel.Transactions.Transaction' referenced from scope '', but it is not definedStack
```

There seems to be some error in my `Select` statement at the end of the `SqlExpression` "exp" definition, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom select projection should use an anonymous Type:

```
.Select<Transaction, Device>((t, d) =>
    new {
      Location = d.Name,
      Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
    });
```

You’d use a POCO when selecting the resultset into the specific concrete Type:

```
var results = db.Select<BottleBox>(q);
```

Comment: So that works only with anonymous objects, but ... why?